# Show portion of image in xsl-fo

Tags: xsl-fo

I need something like this in xsl-fo to show only the part of an image:

```
<div id="sample">
    <img src="img.png">
</div>

#sample{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    overflow:hidden;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#sample img {
    position: absolute;
    top: -100px;
    left: -100px;
}
```

I'm trying with something like this but it doesn't work, shows the full image instead of the portion:

```
<fo:block-container position="absolute" width="400pt" height="400pt">
    <fo:block-container position="relative" left="-300pt" top="-300pt" height="2000pt" width="1600pt">
        <fo:block height="100%" width="100%">
            <fo:external-graphic height="100%" width="100%" content-width="scale-to-fit"  scaling="uniform" src="url('img.png')"/>
        </fo:block>
    </fo:block-container>
</fo:block-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

`overflow` is one of the many properties that are common between CSS and XSL-FO.  See https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#overflow.

Just add `overflow="hidden"` to the `fo:block-container`.

Comment: Thanks Tony. I added it, however I have seen that position:relative is not allowed. https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/compliance.html

So this feature doesn't seem to be possible.

Comment: Sorry.  It works for me with AH Formatter.  You could try replacing '`position="relative" left="-300pt" top="-300pt"`' with '`margin-left="-300pt" margin-top="-300pt"`'.